# How to return a numerical result, when comparing two string values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I want to create a Google Spreadsheet to track in-district driving.  I have previously created a "matrix of sorts" to manually match Location A, Location B, and return a value that I used to place onto our reimbursement form.  I am trying to remove the need for the manual lookup process.

I have two sheets inside a Google Spreadsheet.

- Sheet One is for Data Entry
- Sheet Two is for a summary page

Sheet One looks like this..

[image: Sheet One - Column Headings - Data Validation Drop Down]

You will notice, I am using the Data Validation Drop Down's, this is because we really only have four locations that we typically travel between, and additions/exceptions is something that I think I can adapt the end results for, far easier.

I previously created this, for human lookup purposes.

[image: For Human Use "Mileage Reference"]

What I want is a Google Apps Script attached to the Google Spreadsheet, that will do the following.

On Sheet 1, take the value of B2 - and match it along the vertical values of the mileage reference.  Then Take the Value of C2 and match it along the horizontal values of the mileage reference.  Then have the Script basically do an X-Y type of match, and pull the value and place it into D2.

So as an example.

```
A2=03/06/17 - (Manually Entered by User)
B2=Loc2 - (Selected via Dropdown - Entered by User)
C2=Loc3 - (Selected via Dropdown - Entered by User)
D2=2.3 - (Result entered by Apps Script, after B2 and C2 are populated)
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a brief description of you search/research efforts and if you already wrote some code include it. Reference: [ask]

Answer (score 1):

In Sheet1 with the dropdows in C2 enter:

```
=if(and(B2<>"",C2<>""),vlookup(B2&C2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$17,2,false),"")
```

Copy the formula down column C.

Create Sheet2 in this format:

```
FromTo  Distance
Loc1Loc1    0
Loc1Loc2    0.8
Loc1Loc3    2.1
Loc1Loc4    1
Loc2Loc1    0.8
Loc2Loc2    0
Loc2Loc3    2.3
Loc2Loc4    1
Loc3Loc1    2.1
Loc3Loc2    2.3
Loc3Loc3    0
Loc3Loc4    1.7
Loc4Loc1    1
Loc4Loc2    1
Loc4Loc3    1.7
Loc4Loc4    0
```